# Use BOM from Gradle plugin management

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-bom

We use a BOM to share our dependency management in MyCompany.

It is defined as a Maven POM. Here is a minimal example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>common-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <spring-boot.version>2.4.0</spring-boot.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

It is then used from Gradle projects.

Although this works for code dependencies, I'd like to find out a way to use it from plugin management.

For now, we define in `settings.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {

    val springBootVersion: String by settings

    plugins {
        id("org.springframework.boot") version(springBootVersion)
    }
}
```

`springBootVersion` being defined in the `gradle.properties`.

This is an issue to me because Spring version is defined both:

- in the shared BOM;
- in each project's plugin management.

How can I access to that BOM from Gradle's plugin management?
And if I can't, what is a good don't-repeat-yourself practice to do so?

Comment: wait. if you already have the `bom`, why can't you add your plugin under `build -> pluginManagement -> plugins -> plugin` in that bom, and in all projects use this bom as a parent?

Comment: @Eugene I don't get your point. You may be right but I don't understand your suggestion. Would you detail it a bit more?

Comment: sorry, I re-read the question and took a look of how we do that a bit more closely. and... we don't handle that either, because of [this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/10315). So no, the answer is, until that is fixed (which does not seem in the near future), you simply can't. I don't think it is even worth making this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom platform can provide an opinion about which version of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin you want clients to use (especially since it's not included in the `spring-boot-dependencies` BOM).

Here are the relevant parts of an example platform's `build.gradle.kts` file, for example:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-platform`
}

javaPlatform {
    allowDependencies()
}

dependencies {

    // This platform extends the Spring Boot platform.
    api(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.6"))

    constraints {
        // Provide an opinion about which version of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin clients
        // should use since it's not included in the standard spring-boot-dependencies BOM.
        api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.6")
    }

}
```

That will generate a BOM that aligns both `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` and `spring-boot-dependencies`:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-gradle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Your client projects can then just depend upon your platform and inherit its opinion about the Spring Boot version using something like this:

`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
// Pull in the version of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin specified by your
// platform, making it available to your regular build script.
dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("my-group:my-base-bom:1.0.0"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin")
}
```

`build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") // version inherited from your platform
}

dependencies {
    // It's necessary to specify it for each configuration.
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("my-group:my-base-bom:1.0.0"))

    // Pull in any normal Spring Boot-managed dependencies you need (versions come from platform).
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}
```

Of course, you could also use Gradle [version catalogs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) to centralize versions, which are inlined for clarity in the examples.